# Python: compare series to resampled group quantile and plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am trying to compare my original series with the calculated monthly 90% quantile:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import random

index=pd.date_range('2019-1-1', '2020-1-1', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(100, 10, len(index)), index=index)
quantile20 = df.resample('M').apply(lambda x: x.quantile(0.2))

ax=df.plot(legend=None)
quantile90.plot(ax=ax, legend=None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I would like to highlight the points which fall below the orange line (looks like the picture below).

[image: fig 2]

I tried to assign conditional color on the original series, but those two are not comparable since the resampled series was monthly aggregated.

Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resample your quantile series back to daily (using linear interpolation or just `ffill`) and then be happy.

Comment: Thanks Igor! However, since I'm calculating a monthly quantile, the aggregated series is short for the first month records if I `ffill()` them. It still gives me an error that those two series are not identically-labeled.